# Hartl's Ruby on Rails Section 7.3 Tutorial Sign-up Test Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After coding users_signup_test.rb and expecting a GREEN response, it is still failing for some reason. The tutorial states I should be getting a GREEN response at this phase, but I am not. This is what I receive:

```
1) Error:
UsersSignupTest#test_invalid_signup_information:
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:12:in `create'
    test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
    test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:7:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'

16 runs, 31 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

The only deviation I've had to do from the book that may affect this is one I had to make in the user.rb model and it is as follows:

```
validates( :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255}, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false } )
```

as opposed to the book's:

```
validates( :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255}, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: case_sensitive: false )
```

which would give me an error.

Here is my users_signup_test.rb file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, user: { name: "", email: "user@invalid", password: "foo", password_confirmation: "bar" }
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'
  end

end
```

Let me know if any other code is needed to help diagnose this issue.

As an additional note, I also ran into issues that others have as well using sass-rails 5.0.1 and so I am using sass-rails 5.0.2.

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have well-defined the needed parameters (`user_params` function) when you create an user ? If you're following the tutorial you should end with something like this in your `users_controller.rb`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    # more logic
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Because it looks like you're passing an user parameter that is not permitted by the controller.

Comment: Just posted at the same time. This was it! Thanks for the super fast response!

Comment: You're welcome ! Happy that you found the solution, at the beginning I had very similar problems so don't feel bad. It's hard to get the ruby magic at the beginning hahah.

Comment: Haha, yeah. It can be tricky at times. But it's been incredibly logical. Everything I've run into has been understandable, which is nice. Can't say the same for some other languages :P

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer!

Sorry for the unnecessary post. Researched the error and found it's related to Strong Params. Looking closely at the book, I missed this line:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

which changed from

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

So I wasn't passing the parameters to the controller properly. Sorry everyone!